# How to conditionally render an attribute of state

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to get a dropdown menu to display the name of the topic that a user selected from a previous page (currently, it defaults back to 'Topics').

While I'm able to get `$r.state.topics[$r.state.topicSelected].name` in the console, I get an undefined error when I put `this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected].name` in my code.

So, I'm trying to use conditional rendering to have 'Topics' render as a default while the topics themselves are gathered with a fetch request.

```
<select
value={this.state.topicSelected}
onChange={this.onTopicClick}
className="sort"
data-element>
    {
    // Add this option in the .then() when populating siteCategories()
    [<option key={this.state.topicSelected}
      value={this.state.topicSelected}>({if 
       (this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected].name == undefined) {
       'Topics'
    } else {
    this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected].name
     }})
    </option>].concat(
this.state.topics.map(function (topic) {
 return (<option
 key={topic.id}
 value={topic.id}>{topic.name}</option>);
  }))
 }
</select>
```

I'm getting a unexpected token error, but I've tried various combinations of syntaxes with no luck - how do I properly run this conditional formatting?

Comment: What is this, `$r` ? Do you mean `this`

Comment: Yeah, $r is how you get `this` in the react dev tools on chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary expression `? :`. Like so,

```
this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected] ? this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected].name : 'Topics'
```

Since `undefined` is a falsy value, it will return 'Topics' when `this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected]` is undefined.

```
<select
  value={this.state.topicSelected}
  onChange={this.onTopicClick}
  className="sort"
  data-element>
      <option key={this.state.topicSelected}
        value={this.state.topicSelected}>
        {this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected] ?
         this.state.topics[this.state.topicSelected].name : 'Topics'}
      </option>
      {this.state.topics.map(function (topic) {
         return (<option key={topic.id} value={topic.id}>{topic.name}</option>);
      })}
</select>
```

With the way you have done things, there are some other problems as well, but I didn't see them as relevant to your question. For one, you are changing the first option of the list to be your selected value. Instead, you should be setting the value of the select which automatically selects the correct option from the list. Here's how I would write this:

```
render() {
<select
  value={this.state.topicSelected}
  onChange={this.onTopicClick}
  className="sort"
  data-element>
      <option value={0}>Topics</option>
      {this.state.topics.map(topic => 
             <option key={topic.id} value={topic.id}>{topic.name}</option>))}
</select>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm still getting `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: oh now I understand. let me rewrite it.

Comment: I think I may need to apply the same logic to the `key` and `value` as well - when I select a topic it overwrites 'Topic' so the name of the header appears twice

Comment: With the way you have done things, there are some other problems as well, but I didn't see them as relevant to your question. For one, you are changing the first option of the list to be your selected value. Instead, you should be setting the value of the select which automatically selects the correct option from the list.

Comment: Right, thank you. That's what I'm ultimately trying to achieve, another problem may be that `initialState` is set to `0` so when a user goes back a page, it always defaults to `Topics`

Comment: Yep, that should resolve when you connect the app to a data source, in the meantime, I've added a clean implementation of the select.

Comment: That works well, but I need to find a way to have that selection save when a user goes back a page in their browser

Answer (score 2):

You can also make it a controlled component and default the state as follows

```
function App() {
  const [topics] = useState(["Math", "Geography"]);
  const [selectedTopic, setSelected] = useState("Topic");
  return (
    <select
      value={selectedTopic}
      onChange={(e) => setSelected(e.target.value)}
      className="sort"
    >
      <option>
        Topic
      </option>
      {topics.map(topic => (
        <option key={topic} value={topic}>
          {topic}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

**Class Version of the component**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    topics: ["Math", "Geography"],
    selectedTopic: "Topic",
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedTopic, topics } = this.state;
    return (
      <select
      value={selectedTopic}
      onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selectedTopic: e.target.value })}
      className="sort"
      >
      <option>
        Topic
      </option>
      {topics.map(topic => (
        <option key={topic} value={topic}>
          {topic}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Also in your render method you cannot have an if statement as only javascript expressions are allowed in there. If you need to use conditional statements either use the ternary operator or create a function with the if blocks, that can be called from render. You can read more about expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)

Comment: This would be nicer if written as a class component. (because he is using one, hooks are a totally different learning curve)